# How to fetch all the documents of the MongoDB collection in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to fetch all the documents of the some collection of MongoDB and print certain attributes within each document. But I am unable to do so.

My code:

```
import csv

from pymongo import MongoClient

db_client = MongoClient()

db = db_client.pg_new_sw_cur

db_collection_users = db.pg_new_sw


#with open("pg_details_new.csv",'w') as f:

for post in db_collection_users.find():

        print post['user_name']
        print "==========================="
```

It is printing nothing on the screen after running it when the collection consists of thousands of objects/documents when viewed using RoboMongo.

I am new to MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a wild guess, but I suspect that you have specified an incorrect collection name:

```
db_collection_users = db.pg_new_sw
```

Recheck that `pg_new_sw` actually exists in your local `MongoDB` server instance and contains documents inside.

Comment: thanks :) ! silly me .. this was the error although I rechecked thrice but still couldn't make it out

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA phew, it was risky to make this guess, but glad to see it's solved.